# Expected 'MappingStart', got 'SequenceStart'

Tags: .net, docker

I am trying to get started with Docker and I seem to be having problems every single step of the way.  Seeing lots of vague errors.  I have created an ASP.NET Core application and enabled Docker support, which worked as expected.

I am now trying to create an SQL database service, so I have edited the compose file as follows:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sql.data:
    sql.data:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux
    environment:
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Pass@word
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
    ports:
      - "5434:1433"
  webapplication2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}webapplication2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication2/Dockerfile
```

as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/database-server-container

Here is the output:

```
error : (Line: 7, Col: 7, Idx: 107) - (Line: 7, Col: 7, Idx: 107): Expected 'MappingStart', got 'SequenceStart' (at Line: 7, Col: 7, Idx: 107).
1>Done building project "docker-compose.dcproj" -- FAILED.
```

What is the problem? So far I have looked here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/248013/docker-project-fails-to-build-after-upgrade-to-vis.html - removing the dashes did not seem to help.

The YAML appears to parse here: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/.  If I remove the SQL.Data service then it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a [bug with VS/Dockertools](https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/98). You can use an alternative notation:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sql.data:
    sql.data:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux
    environment:
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD : Pass@word
      ACCEPT_EULA : Y
      MSSQL_PID : Developer
    ports:
      - "5434:1433"
  webapplication2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}webapplication2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication2/Dockerfile
```

Note that you must have a space on either side of the colon (:).

Answer (score 0):

Your YAML, as presented is valid YAML, and the error message is from the YAML parser (i.e. not a the level of the interpretation of the data by DockerCompose. So the error is probably hidden from normal view in your original file, because there is either a TAB character in the input (there should not be), or because you have incorrect/mixed line endings (CR+LF instead of just LF)

My guess is that one of sequence elements (the one starting with the dashes) has a tab (+ spaces) instead of 6 spaces.